# Universal bucket in Google Cloud Platform for content, which would determine the user's location and serve content from the closest server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cdn, google-cloud-cdn

I am a mobile application developer. I use Google Cloud bucket to store 10-second videos and photos that I use in the application. Thousands of users use the application every day, and I want to use a CDN to ensure that the content of the application is delivered to users with minimum delays and maximum speed.

At the moment, I have only found an opportunity to create a bucket within one region to choose from: the USA, Europe, and Asia. How to create a universal bucket in Google Cloud Platform for storing application content, which would determine the user's location and serve content from the server closest to the user?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use a CDN which provides far more locations than a global bucket (which does not exist). Google's CDN has approximately 100 edge locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of Cloud CDN (fully) when you use an HTTP(S) Load Balancer since it's a global resource, meaning that your bucket traffic would be forwarded to a GCP Point of Presence (PoP) near all the clients worldwide.

If interested, here's [how to](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-bucket) do it, but keep in mind that you would (potentially) need to change your DNS value from current bucket to the new Load Balancer, and HTTP --> HTTPS redirection is not implemented by default (you can achieve an automatic redirect with [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect), but this is something you would need to setup separatedly).

On an additional note, depending on how many files (similar) are requested from your bucket, you will be charged less than it would be considered CDN traffic and not full GCP traffic.

So in short, your bucket data would be on your selected region, but CDN would be all around the globe meaning less latency, less price and your backend not being overwhelmed (this doesn't apply here since you are using buckets, but would apply for backend GCE instances).